# Is there an income tax liability for an Indian receiving remittance from a US-based Company?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, india

My son is studying (for his undergraduate degree) in India and he has an Education Loan also.

He works for US-based company as an intern, and he is getting a stipend. The stipend is remitted by the US-based company, from the US to my son in India.
Is this remittance Taxable as per the Income Tax Act in India?

Comment: Hi Santosh, I edited the question to be a little more clear - you are welcome to edit in additional details if I was mistaken in my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this should be treated as income and taxes paid as per the tax brackets.

Taxes have to be paid every quarter.